# why can i not install ubuntu server edition on my server

Tags: server

I go to the completed download file but I can not find a `setup.exe` like Windows and there is not a setup file in the folder. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Ubuntu is an operating system, not an application. What are you trying to accomplish? What's the goal that motivates you to try to install Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Maybe you should start here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-server

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is not an application, but an operating system. It doesn't run on Windows, it runs instead of Windows. You downloaded an ISO image: burn it onto a CD-ROM (you can do this from Windows), then put the CD-ROM into your CD drive and reboot the server. If you have no CD drive, use the [live USB creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) to create a bootable USB stick and boot from that instead.